# Find all strings in NSArray that are a particular length

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, nsarray

I have an `NSArray` filled with 200,000 words, where each word could have 1-10 characters.
I would like to create a second array based on the first, containing only the words that have exactly 5 characters.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [predicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSPredicate) to [filter the array](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/filteredArrayUsingPredicate%3a) and produce a new array containing only those words whose length is 5. Something like:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length == 5"];
NSArray *fiveCharWords = [myWordList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
```

I always seem to get the [predicate format](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) slightly wrong the first time around, so don't be surprised if there's an error there. The point is that you should read up on NSPredicate and learn about how you can use predicates to filter collections like arrays and sets.

Comment: THanks for this!! I will look into NSPredicate for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Filter the array with a predicate where the predicate compares the `length` to `5`. Or loop and copy the appropriate values to another array.

Answer (score 0):

Using your data model I would use a For Loop and parse through the data and when I find an object in Array1 that has a length > 5 I would commit it to Array2. I would also start by googling NSArray and For Loop in regards to ObjectiveC.

Using a different data model I would throw all of the Array1 data into a SQLLite database so your app runs a lot faster.

Comment: thanks, that was my original idea. The SQLLite database seems a good option to explore. Thanks!

Comment: The SQLLite route has its advantages & disadvantages and may be overkill if you have a static data set but it's yet another option. I suppose a more pertinent clarification is how important performance is to you. If you're pre-loading the data into the app the SQLLite makes sense. If you're loading the data app-side I would personally use the SQLLite method. If the data is pre-loaded into the Array somehow I would skip SQLLite since you'd have to parse it anyway and can easily just throw it into Array2. Similar question around whether or not the data is static or dynamic.